# Why do I get empty string from reading non-empty cell in xlsx file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm having trouble with reading an xlsx file. Basically, if I read it other than top to bottom, I get empty String from missed rows. For instance, if I read row 5 and then any row from 1 to 4, I get no answer whereas the cells are not empty and can be read if I do so before reading row 5.

I use org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
and com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader

Anyone having such trouble?

**edit 1:**
The whole code is quite lengthy but the method I created to read a given cell is:

```
private static String getCellValue(Sheet sheet, int rowNum, int column) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        if (row.getRowNum() != rowNum) {
            continue;
        }
        Cell cell = row.getCell(column);
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I use a foreach loop because sheet.getRow(rowNum) doesn't work either. To read different cells, I call this method multiple times so the fact that I use a foreach loop shouldn't be the cause of the trouble.

I also tried using the XSSF import but then I can read some cells but not all which confuses me even more.

**edit 2 :**
The call happens here:

```
try (Workbook wb = StreamingReader.builder().bufferSize(BUFFER).open(tmp)) {
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(SHEET_NUMBER);
    for (FieldEnum field : FieldEnum.getAllMandatory()) {
        fieldMap.put(field, getCellValue(sheet, field.getRow(), field.getColumn()));
    }
}
```

where tmp is the xlsx file, FieldEnum an enum containing info about the xlsx file (cell name, cell number, ...) and fieldMap a Map between FieldEnum and String with String value the content of the corresponding cell.

**edit 3:**
I just figured out that when I get no answer is because the return in the foreach loop is never reached. I don't know yet if it's because the loop itself isn't triggered or if it is but the continue is always triggered. The initialisation of the rowNum and column happens in the FieldEnum and this is where if I switch the order of the fields around, I can or cannot read the cell value.

**edit 4:**
So I do enter the foreach loop but for some reason I never get passed the if condition

Comment: Whats the code? The import alone doesnt help at all

Comment: To possibly get better answers you should mention that you are using [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) which not is `apache poi` but is basing on `apache poi`. But as I suspect this "Streaming Reader" simply is not made getting random rows from the sheet. As it's name says, it streams the sheet data not keeping them in memory. Thus it has lower memory consumption. So why not using the methods directly from [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Axel. Actually, I'm just learning on this technology so I just used this without knowing it could have such limitations. I didn't know this isn't apache poi as it's litterally written on the import. I guess you're right about the fact that the Streaming Reader doesn't keep data in memory. I will look into your proposal to use methods directly from apache poi. Thank you!

**edit :** Ok so I looked into the code and you're right about apache poi. I'm actually using "import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;" but I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Axel Richter, I have solved my issue thanks to you!

You were right about the fact that StreamingReader only streams the data and doesn't store it afterwards. So to read different rows, using an Enum to organise cell data, one must read them in order and to read multiple cells in one row, one must either read them all at once (when the row is first instantiated) or store the row in a static variable to be accessed afterwards.

Basically, I have to order my enum by rowNum and make sure different cells in the same row are declared at the same time (one after the other without any other cell from other rows in between).